# What is the purpose of setuptools requirements of the form "package===version"

Tags: python, setuptools

Say I have a package with a console script such as

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='eg_package',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Trivial test package',
    packages=[
       'eg_package',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = eg_package.main:main',
        ]
   },
)
```

If I set and explicit build tag using `egg_info -b mytag` the resulting script has `__requires__ = 'eg-package===0.0.1mytag'`, i.e. with 3 "=" signs.  This occurs when the tag is not something conventional like `b1` for a beta release.

At first I thought this was a bug but the setuptools documentation suggests it is a valid requirement identifier.  However, it doesn't work with older versions of setuptools which is causing problems with our systems.

My question is what does `"==="` mean and why does modern `setuptools` use it?

Comment: You can find an official description of `===` in PEP440 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#arbitrary-equality

Comment: Thanks, that's very sensible.  I was used to the more permissive rules of earlier versions of setuptools but I'm happy to be forced into stricter version strings.  It's a pity this isn't mentioned in the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/search.html) or the [packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/).

Comment: My particular issue was that a build system running the latest setuptools is building debian packages that will be installed into vanilla ubuntu systems which do not have latest setuptools => PEP440 requirement descriptions are not supported.

Comment: @StephenPascoe: PEP 440 is linked in the [version section](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#version) of the packaging guide.

Comment: @cel "Use of this operator is heavily discouraged and tooling MAY display a warning when it is used."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Requirement specifier section in `pip` docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirement-specifiers) links to the [official docs for requirement specifiers implemented by `setuptools` `pkg_resources`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#requirement-objects). It specifies the formal syntax but says nothing on the semantics.
[Overview docs](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies) explain semantics but say nothing on the `~=` and `===` stuff that were apparently added somewhere between vv.7 (installed with python 2.7.9) and 16.

When docs fail, it's time to consult the sources. Downloading the [setuptools hg repo](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools) and annotating `pkg_resources/__init__.py` ultimately brings us to [changeset 3125](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/commits/dcd552da643c4448056de84c73d56da6d70769d5) with the message *"Implement PEP 440 by using the packaging library".*

Indeed, [PEP 440, Version Specifiers section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) explains the syntax and semantics:

> - ~= : [Compatible release](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release) clause
>     <...>
> - === : [Arbitrary equality](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#arbitrary-equality) clause.

By examining other files in the commit and the related `packaging` package, I came to these apparent conclusions:

- `~=` is never produced; when handled<sup>1</sup>, it acts as a filter according to the rules outlined in the PEP.
- `===`, when handled, signals to fall back to the older `setuptools` version syntax and comparison logic. It is produced whenever the resulting version string doesn't conform to the PEP<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>
<sub>In `pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.specifiers._compare_compatible()`</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>`pkg_resources.parse_version()` produces a `pkg_resources.SetuptoolsLegacyVersion` rather than `pkg_resources.SetuptoolsVersion`</sub>