# What are triple equal signs and ubuntu2 in Python pip freeze?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, pip

On my AWS Ubuntu 14.04 instance I just did a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which gave me a file which also includes the following two lines:

```
python-apt===0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-debian===0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
```

When I then use this file to do a `pip install -r requirements.txt` on a another AWS Ubuntu 14.04 instance I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 262, in run
    for req in parse_requirements(filename, finder=finder, options=options, session=session):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1632, in parse_requirements
    req = InstallRequirement.from_line(line, comes_from, prereleases=getattr(options, "pre", None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 173, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 71, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'python-apt===0.9.3.5ubuntu2', 'at', '0.9.3.5ubuntu2')
```

I wonder about two things here:

1. Why does `pip freeze` use the `ubuntu2` at the end of the version?
2. Why does `pip freeze` use the `===` instead of `==`?

[EDIT]

And one more question:

3. Why does pip on the other machine not accept the `===` and the `ubuntu2` (I tried both separately)?

Comment: I think this is the correct duplicate, it's a little tricky to find: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331314/what-is-the-purpose-of-setuptools-requirements-of-the-form-package-version/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `===` is the [arbitrary equality clause](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#arbitrary-equality) and is defined in PEP-0440:

> Arbitrary equality comparisons are simple string equality operations
>   which do not take into account any of the semantic information such as
>   zero padding or local versions. This operator also does not support
>   prefix matching as the == operator does.
>
> The primary use case for arbitrary equality is to allow for specifying
>   a version which cannot otherwise be represented by this PEP. This
>   operator is special and acts as an escape hatch to allow someone using
>   a tool which implements this PEP to still install a legacy version
>   which is otherwise incompatible with this PEP.
>
> An example would be ===foobar which would match a version of foobar .
>
> This operator may also be used to explicitly require an unpatched
>   version of a project such as ===1.0 which would not match for a
>   version 1.0+downstream1 .
>
> Use of this operator is heavily discouraged and tooling MAY display a
>   warning when it is used.

You should upgrade your version of pip on the target machine (`pip install --upgrade pip`) and it should not display the error message.