# How to install `distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1`?

Tags: django, pip, pyproject.toml

Trying to modernize an old Django project (2.2), and its `requirements.txt` (generated via `pip freeze`) has some lines that make `pip install` throw fits:

```
distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
```

I interpreted the errors I got for the first one (see the error output in its entirety at the bottom) as the version string not conforming to [PEP-518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/), but it doesn't even mention the `===` operator. This SO thread, [What are triple equal signs and ubuntu2 in Python pip freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434133/what-are-triple-equal-signs-and-ubuntu2-in-python-pip-freeze), has a similar issue, but:

1. The errors they got is different (`ValueError` as opposed to my `ParseError`).
2. The solution was to upgrade `pip`, but I'm already using the latest one.

Now, `pip install distro-info` works so should I just go with that?

---

**update**: The project I'm trying to update has been conceived around 2020, and according to the [PyPI history of `distro-info`](https://pypi.org/project/distro-info/#history), it had a `0.10` release in 2013 and a `1.0` in 2021. Could this anything have to do with the weird `pip freeze` output? (From [this PyPI support issue](https://github.com/pypi/support/issues/589).)

---

The error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3021, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 102, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyparsing/core.py", line 1141, in parse_string
    raise exc.with_traceback(None)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected string_end, found '('  (at char 12), (line:1, col:13)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3101, in __init__
    super(Requirement, self).__init__(requirement_string)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 104, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'(===0.18'": Expected string_end

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 400, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 373, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 213, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_updated_criteria(candidate)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 203, in _get_updated_criteria
    for requirement in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate=candidate):
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 237, in get_dependencies
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 237, in <listcomp>
    return [r for r in candidate.iter_dependencies(with_requires) if r is not None]
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 247, in iter_dependencies
    requires = self.dist.iter_dependencies() if with_requires else ()
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/pkg_resources.py", line 216, in iter_dependencies
    return self._dist.requires(extras)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2736, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3023, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3033, in _compute_dependencies
    reqs.extend(parse_requirements(req))
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3094, in parse_requirements
    yield Requirement(line)
  File "/home/old-django-project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3103, in __init__
    raise RequirementParseError(str(e))
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Parse error at "'(===0.18'": Expected string_end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your library was discontinued. In [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/distro-info/#history), infact, I can see there are only `1.0` and `0.10`. If you need that specific version, then you need to setup a manual installation, downloading the source [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/distro-info/0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1). Either, you can upgrade your version and try to refactor any possible problem coming after!

In case, if you need to dockerize your app, setting up a script for the manual installation of a library is simple.

Comment: "_try to refactor any possible problem coming after!_" - the magic phrase for most dependency-related tasks on any language and platform:) On the other hand, if I understood your answer correctly, `0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1` **was** a valid version on PyPI that was subject to disappear at any moment (hence the [PEP-440 designation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/)), and it had to be specified with `===`. `pip freeze` simply saved it thus as this was installed at the time, but never upgraded. Right?

Comment: exactly! for minor libraries, it is very common for them to disappear from the official repositories.. but luckily, a source code will always fly around the internet :D

Comment: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/distro-info/-/tree/debian/0.18